# Flutter show incoming call

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I created a video calling application but for the moment, when somebody wants to call a person, the receiver is getting a push notification to start the call.
I want to be able to show an incoming call screen, something like WhatsApp does or Facebook.
Are there any 3rd party packages you know about and I couldn't find or am I stuck on using APN and Activities?

I tried by now looking on how bridging works but looks like a lot of work and aiI'm not entirely sure I can actually complete it.

Comment: any luck on this and what video call api are you using? please

Comment: I ended up implementing a bridge for the IOS Callkit and ConnectionService from Android native.

Comment: @ModreanuEduard is it possible, to share your implementation of the ios and android bridge?

Comment: hii any update guys? stuck at same situation..

Comment: any solution? same issue

Comment: Have  you tried with https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep @AbdullahKhan ?

Comment: @LuisA.Chaglla yes but it didn't meet our requirements, this feature is currently on hold.

Comment: @ModreanuEduard when receiving the notification, if the app is on foreground you can do/display whatever you want, I mean you can display the incoming call page instead of the notification, for the notification on background I'm not sure if you can replace to but you still can show the incoming call page when the notification is clicked, it is not what you want exactly but it does the job temporarlly

Comment: Have you tried Agora?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit) in order to implement a call system.

Comment: From my limited research, this is the only package that does the job. However, it can only be used with connectycube service only. But tested with it and it works great!